# CSS3 diaporama, how to make the change gradual?

Tags: html, css, css-animations, keyframe

I'm making a diaporama in pure css, and so far so good, however each pic changes to the other abruptly and i'm trying to make the change gradual (one pic disapearing slowly while the other appears).

I've tried with all timing functions (except cubic-bezier since i'm not too sure how to use it yet) and it hasn't worked.

How to make the changes gradual? I've seen someone doing it with only css3 but I haven't been able to reproduce it.

**Here is the css** **and the html**

```css
.diapo {
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 3px solid #544B4D;
  background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/350x150/F00");
  background-size: 350px 150px;
  animation-name: diapo1;
  animation-duration: 9s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: normal;
}

@keyframes diapo1 {
  0% {
    background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/350x150/F00");
  }
  33% {
    background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/350x150/0F0");
  }
  66% {
    background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/350x150/00F");
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="diapo">
  </div>
</body>
```

Thanks for any answer!

Comment: I've updated your question with public images and turns out it works for me. (Mac + Latest Chrome)

Comment: tbh, I don't think you are doing it properly, but an answer with a proper way would take too much time. Basically you should have multiple images in your DOM and animate their opacity. then you just set a different animation-delay on each of them. With a bit of calculations based on how many images you have you should be good to go

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Still new around here.
It does work, but not gradually!
Would it be because of mozilla 58 ?

Comment: It is gradual on my setup

Comment: I dont think ff support this

Comment: I'm not sure to fully understand are,you suggesting to have the 3 images shown together, but gradually change the opacity of 2 of them (one augmenting, and one lowering?) on each percentage of the keyframe?

Comment: You set them on top of each other with absolue position. With for eg 3 images. Each one should be visible 1/3 of the time (with opacity 1) but not at the same time. You can use animation-delay: totalTime*i*1/3 where i is the img index

Comment: However it would be really easier and reliable with a bit of JS

Comment: Yes, I'm sure too. However I'm learning by myself and I want to go to the bottom of things.
I will learn js as soon as I feel I have achieved good proefiency in CSS3 and HTML5.
Thanks for the tip though! I surely will follow it!

Comment: I took some time to post a proof of concept so you can see what I meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, the best solution is to use multiple img in the DOM combined with some opacity animations:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  /* Define size on the container: (best if aligned with images size) */
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  
  /* fancy stuff, not required */
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container > img {
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  
  /* images are stacked on top of each other */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  
  opacity: 0;
  
  /* 10s is total time (time for a complete cycle) */
  animation: fadeInOut 10s infinite;
}

.container > img:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 3.33s; /* totalTime * 1/3 */
}
.container > img:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 6.66s; /* totalTime * 2/3 */
}

/* choose a % of anim time allocated to transition,
let's call it transTime. Here it's 10%. */
@keyframes fadeInOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  /* transTime */
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  /* transTime + (100% / image count) */
  43% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  /* previous + transTime */
  53% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150/F00"/>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150/0F0"/>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150/00F"/>
</div>
```

I strongly advise you to use a preprocessor that allow variables and loops (maybe SCSS or Less) to generate the `nth-child` section and even the animation block

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that most browser can interprete a change in background-image gradually... How can they interprete that change ? Should it mean the picture slides from the top, should it mean a fade out/fade in, should it mean a fade in of the new picture above the old one ?

I think you'd need to animate a fade out/in (The code below might not work as is, it is just to give you an idea) :

```
@keyframes diapo1 {
  0% {
    background-image: url("pics-about-us/a-u1.jpeg");
  }
  30% { opacity:1;}
  33% {
    background-image: url("pics-about-us/a-u3.jpeg");
    opacity:0;
  }
  36% {opacity:1}
  //etc...
```

If you want to do it with a gradual change over the whole animation, I would use on `<div>` child per background image and animate each individually.